# If there is an injection of a set into one of its subset then it is also a bijection

Tags: elementary-set-theory

This is an exercise from my set theory lecture notes:

> Let $A$ be a set and $B$⊆$A$.  If $f$: $A$→$B$ is an injection then it is also a bijection.

My attempt:

Define $g$: $B$ →$A$ such that $g$($b$) = $b$ for all $b$ in $B$. Note that this is also an injection.

Now, $B$ = im$f$ ∪ $B$∖im$f$. It is enough to show that the second set of the union is empty.

Assume that $B$∖im$f$ is non empty. This implies there is a $b$ in $B$ such that $f^-1($b$)$ does not exist.

Here, $f$o$g$: $B$ →$B$. Since $f$ and $g$ are injections so is $f$o$g$. Injection from a set to itself is always a bijection. This implies [$f$o$g$]^-1        exists. So, [$f$o$g$]^-1($b$) exists. This means $g$^-1 o $f$^-1 ($b$) exists. Which further implies that $g$^-1[$f$^-1($b$)] exists and hence $f$^-1($b$) exists which is a contradiction.

Is this incorrect? Am I assuming things I shouldn't? Any sort of feedback is appreciated.

Comment: It is simply not true that $B\setminus Im(f)=\emptyset$. Consider $f:\mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}\setminus\{0\}, f(n)=2n.$

Comment: Also injections from a set to itself need not be a bijection (this is only true for finite sets). Consider $$h:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow \mathbb{N}, h(n)=2n,$$ this is an injection and no bijection.

Comment: What is true in your setting, there exists a bijection from $A$ to $B$. This follows from the Cantor-Bernstein theorem. Have you checked the assumptions/precise wording of your exercise?